# PHP Unable to determine user's browser information

Tags: php, browser, localhost

I want to determine which user uses which browser when they visit to my website.
For this process i'am using `$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']` but when i try to print it while i'am using chrome i get this result(on localhost):

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.153 Safari/537.36
```

What can i do to fix that ? Any help would be appriciated

Comment: "Fix"? Fix what? Nothing appears to be broken. What makes you think something needs fixing?

Comment: @Quentin I think it isn't print the true browser info

Comment: You're wrong, that is the user-agent information that Chrome sends.

Comment: @Quentin so how can get the browser name via PHP ?

Comment: Keep an up to date set of rules to convert the user agent into a browser name that you find useful and pass the UA string through those rules.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']
```

This gives the information of the browser as you said.
Always keep in mind that HTTP_USER_AGENT can be easily spoofed by the user.

[get_browser()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.get-browser.php) gives the browser's capability.

you can also use the php class provided by [Wolfcast](https://github.com/Wolfcast/BrowserDetection)
use like:

```
$browser = new BrowserDetection();
echo 'You are using ', $browser->getBrowser(), ' version ', $browser->getVersion();
```

if you really want to differentiate the browsers from the client-side you could use the javascript to find the browser and apply the changes through that based on different browser.

this is a code that i obtained from internet that exactly differentiate the browsers.

```
var isOpera = !!window.opera || navigator.userAgent.indexOf(' OPR/') >= 0;
var isFirefox = typeof InstallTrigger !== 'undefined';   // Firefox 1.0+
var isChrome = !!window.chrome && !isOpera;        // Chrome 1+

if(isFirefox){
    //do the change
} else if (isChrome){
    //do the change
}
```

Comment: i can't use Javascript because i need it for a back-end process.